# WordPress site auto updates for no reason

Tags: automatic-updates, version-control

I have a WP site currently running 4.7.2 version, and I use version control system. I did check both file configurations and database, there is nothing to force the site to auto update, also there are no plugins installed for that purpose. Still the site keeps updates to the latest version. If I understand correctly when WP detects version control systems it stops the updates, is that correct? If yes, could someone point me to the correct direction on what to check out next?

Comment: WordPress will always automatically update to latest version until you force it not to download any update.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will always automatically update,if you want to stop it use:

define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );

Comment: I don't want to stop it, I have other 3 sites cloned from the original and modified a bit, but they don't update automatically, so I'm trying to figure it out why those are behaving differently.

Comment: compare that other 3 sites wp-config.php file with this site's wp-config.php file,may be there is some variable defined for auto update.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and they look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I used one-click installer from my cPanel. If you had done the same, don't bother looking elsewhere and go straight to the installer settings pages and uncheck automated framework updates.

Comment: No, the machine that are installed on is not using cPanel it is an Ubuntu machine that you manage with plain old CLI...

Comment: In that case, you may either use a plugin like [WP Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stops-core-theme-and-plugin-updates/) or use disable from wp-config.

Comment: So, far the only thing that affects the site is to use a plugin, even if I put configurations on the config.php the site keep behaving the same. However I'm trying to avoid using any new plugins...

Comment: You may work around two of the [relevant queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates)

Comment: From what I understand, Wordpress will force only minor updates except when the settings aren't overridden. I would still try a plugin though.

Comment: Do you think a plugin might be more consistent? I did try the config queries with not much luck, I even tried to compare the databases in order to figure it out but nothing, all look the same...

Comment: @Alimba Absolutely, WP Plugin Directory is a pretty decent piece of code. Things we novices do in order to make Wordpress websites work!